# Aligning elements in table

Tags: html, html-table

I would like for top 4 elements to stretch across the top, and bottom two  to also look like they belong to the same table, stretch and not be so squeezed. Can I accomplish this without adding empty `<td>`s?

This is how it looks like right now:
[image: table]
http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=F0OOEL3HH55Y

My code:

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="650" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="8" class="header" width="300">Weight Per Book (lb.)</td>
        <td height="8" class="header" width="300">Cost per Book</td>
        <td height="8" class="header" width="200">Quantity for whole order</td>
        <td height="8" class="header" width="400">Capability Complexity Level For TO</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="16">2.0</td>
        <td height="16">0.00</td>
        <td height="16">0</td>
        <td height="16">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="bottom">
        <td class="header">Distribute ID Order to Home Plant</td>
        <td class="header">Distribute All OTR's to Home Plant</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `colspan` attribute to do that. This attribute define the number of columns a particular cell should span.

Here is an example:

```html
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width="650" border="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Production</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="8" class="header" width="300">Weight Per Book (lb.)</td>
    <td height="8" class="header" width="300">Cost per Book</td>
    <td height="8" class="header" width="200">Quantity for whole order</td>
    <td height="8" class="header" width="400">Capability Complexity Level For TO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="16">2.0</td>
    <td height="16">0.00</td>
    <td height="16">0</td>
    <td height="16">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="bottom">
    <td colspan="2" class="header">Distribute ID Order to Home Plant</td>
    <td colspan="2" class="header">Distribute All OTR's to Home Plant</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">No</td>
    <td colspan="2">No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!